# PHP DateTime using Static Object vs New Object

Tags: php, oop, datetime, object

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method? In which case should I create a new object and when should I use the static call? Is DateTime an exception?

In this case the method call for `format()` seems to work for both.

Both the `$dateObj` and the `$dateStatic` work similarly in this case:

```
<?php
$raw = '22. 11. 1968';

$dateObj1 = new DateTime ();
$dateObj2= $dateObj1->createFromFormat('d. m. Y', $raw);
echo 'Start date: ' . $dateObj2->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";

$dateStatic = DateTime::createFromFormat('d. m. Y', $raw);
echo 'Start date: ' . $dateStatic->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The static method is preferable. It will have slightly better performance. Your first method is creating a new DateTime object and then immediately replacing it with a new DateTime object. Serves no purpose.

Comment: +1, I can confirm that static method is ~2 times faster (actually, it's an alias for date_create_from_format)